# Migrating Wordpress (MySQL) database to BigQuery

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-bigquery

I am not that technical so please excuse my miss-use of terms.

I want to start a reddit styles site for a niche community. I am thinkin about building an MVP using a wordpress theme I found. I know that it isn't scalable and won't be quick enough if the site takes off but it is cheap and easy for me to setup.

I would ideall like to use Wordpress for the first 2000 users and then migrate to something more scalable at a later date. I know bigquery is fast and scalable so it would be a good option.

How easy would it be to migrate the databases over? Is it really stupid to use Wordpress at first?

Any other advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BigQuery is a great database to analyze data - but not a great database to run your website on.

Choosing the right database for your project requires knowing a lot of details you are not providing - but as if you mention you are "not that technical", MySQL is a pretty good solution that can scale to way more than 2,000 users - but that will require technical knowledge.

In the meantime, watch one of my favorite videos on the SQL vs NoSQL debate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRoy6I4gKWU. Forget about BigQuery for a while, until you have interesting data to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that it isn't scalable and won't be quick enough if the site
>   takes off...

WordPress and MySQL is perfectly scalable to millions of users. What you need - like anything else - is the hardware. I've used WordPress sites with thousands of users on inexpensive shared hosting. The key is the *hardware*, not WordPress or MySQL itself.

On a VPS or dedicated, configure MySQL for high loads; use mysqltuner.pl or other utilities to configure my.cnf. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=my.cnf+configure

Run multiple databases on multiple servers, if needed. http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+scalable

If you need to access different databases, either use PHP or use the WordPress database layer. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb